# Fatal Error: OgreCgPlugin.h: No Such File or Directory (Ogre3d)

Tags: c++, ogre3d

After attempting to install Ogre3d from source for Linux, it all built properly but I realized that I had built static libraries. I re-built using CMake again, this time un-ticking the static option. When I create a new Ogre Project in code::blocks and try to compile, I get:

```
 __________________________________________________ ____ _________________________________________________________
| /usr/local/include/OGRE/OgreStaticPluginLoader.h | 28 | fatal error: OgreCgPlugin.h: No such file or directory |
|__________________________________________________|____|________________________________________________________|
```

I got this error with both the static and dynamic builds of Ogre3d. Note that I did not change any settings after creating the project, just clicked compile. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think Ogre has some .cfg that you need to put in your program's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost sounds like when you recompiled (after unchecking static), it didn't install the files afterward, as at some time during the build process it generates a file called OgreBuildSettings.h that holds this information (in this case, it's defining `OGRE_STATIC_LIB`, despite the fact that you unchecked it.)

If you ran cmake directly from the Ogre repository directory, I'd recommend checking out a clean copy of the Ogre source and rebuilding.

One thing that might be helpful - generally when I'm building it, I'll follow a pattern along the lines of:

`cd /path/to/ogre; mkdir build && cd build && cmake-gui .. && make && sudo make install`

This has the benefit of keeping my build configuration separate from the source, lets me have separate build directories for dynamic and static builds, and (most importantly) allows me to just remove the build directory and start over quickly, in the event that I screwed something up. (:

Comment: Okay now I'v attempted to delete all traces of Ogre as hard as I possibly can, downloaded the source again and it is currently building, hopefully, in the non-static way :)

Comment: I'v recompiled and everything but now I get "error while loading shared libraries: libOgreMain.so.1.7.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Eli - I'm assuming you did a `make install` after recompiling - do you know where it put the libraries after installing? Also, you may need to reload the library cache if you're using Linux, e.g., `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: (just for the info its Ell as in Elliot :) ) It seemed that sudo ldconfig did something because now I get a load of text about creating groups and registering things but I now I'm getting an exception, here is the message: [link](http://pastebin.com/LzrXTM1g)

Comment: Okay, I finally got it working by copying the config files! Thanks for your help!